# Linq query for finding one-to-one relation inside a table

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say we have two columns in a table called A and B. I want to write a linq query in c# which returns back the rows for which column A just corresponds to ONE UNIQUE column B.

example 1:
A B
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
3 1

returns:
A B
2 1
3 1

example 2:
A B
1 1
1 1
2 1
3 1

returns: 
A B
1 1
2 1
3 1

In example 2, column A has value 1 and it corresponds to JUST ONE UNIQUE column B value(1). So in results, 1, 1 should appear also.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Doesn't seem like a very complex thing to do with LINQ.

Comment: I am very new into linq query. I tried groupby based queries. But it did not do what I wanted to. Could you please help me with the query?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it, probably not very efficient:

```
        List<Tuple<int, int>> testData = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

        testData.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1));
        testData.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2));
        testData.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 3));
        testData.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(2, 1));
        testData.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(3, 1));

        List<Tuple<int, int>> result = testData
           .Distinct() //remove duplicates
           .GroupBy(x => x.Item1) //groups by column A
           .Select(x => x.ToList()) //transform into a list of lists
           .Where(x => x.Count() == 1) //selects lists that have only one item
           .Select(x => x[0]) //flattens the list to a single list
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the answer for you and it works on both cases that you wrote and even if the number at the second column is not 1 but it unique:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> testData = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1),
    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1),
    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1),
    new Tuple<int, int>(2, 1),
    new Tuple<int, int>(3, 1),
    new Tuple<int, int>(4, 2),
    new Tuple<int, int>(4, 2)
};

var filteredData = testData
  .GroupBy(l => l.Item1)
  .Select(g => new
  {
    Item1 = g.Key,
    Count = g.Select(l => l.Item2).Distinct().Count()
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: it works fine. if you want it as a List just  put .ToList() at the end. i updated the answer with it.